# Place Order Button Not Working

Tags: checkout, magento-1, magento-1.5, place-order

Hi I am having an issue with my magento site. The place order button is not working at all.

Here is a screenshot of the errors I am getting on inspect:
[image]

Can anyone help me please?
Magento Version: Magento ver. 1.5.1.0 and using Onepage

Comment: Wow! You are using a very outdated version of Magento... The problem would likely be resolved if you upgrade to a more recent one.  Magento 1.X versions can be found [HERE](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download) under the "Release Archive" tab.  Also, you should not have this tagged as a Magento 2 question if it doesn't apply to Magento 2,

Comment: I can't upgrade at the moment.

Comment: Ok.  Have you made any changes to the referenced `prototype.js` or `detector.js`?  Also, there is a chance that this could be related to any customizations in `skin/frontend/base/default/js/checkout/opcheckout.js` or any theme-fallback files that you have in place..

Comment: I haven't touched anything at all. Woke up today to the button not functioning which is the weird part.

Comment: Do you know `login.js` and `detector.js`? Could it be [malware](https://magento.com/security/news/new-javascript-malware-issue)